# How to separate the RGB colour space to only N colours?

Tags: jpeg, color-spaces, rgb

In a JPEG image, we may have thousands of distinct RGB values.
What is the process called of translating these numerous RGB values to just N distinct colour names/values?
(I'd like to know the name for the process so I could read on it).

I want to create a Python script that will get a JPEG as input and convert each pixel to only N colour names.
E.g., assume my colours are as in the table below.
I'd like to go over each pixel in the input image, find the RGB value in the table that is the closest to the current pixel's RGB value, and output for that pixel the corresponding colour name.

For instance, (220,0,12), (224,5,15), (223,1,10), and (216, 2,11) should all be translated to 'bright red'.

| Colour | R | G | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| medium blue | 70 | 138 | 196 |
| bright orange | 229 | 28 | 23 |
| transparent brown | 165 | 144 | 129 |
| transparent medium reddish-violet | 236 | 155 | 193 |
| bright yellowish-green | 147 | 183 | 10 |
| bright reddish-violet | 154 | 0 | 96 |
| transparent bright bluish-violet | 155 | 148 | 198 |
| silver | 139 | 146 | 148 |
| sand blue | 93 | 115 | 138 |
| sand yellow | 139 | 115 | 81 |
| earth blue | 0 | 35 | 63 |
| earth green | 0 | 51 | 21 |
| transparent flourescent blue | 205 | 226 | 245 |
| metallic dark grey | 72 | 62 | 58 |
| sand green | 94 | 128 | 100 |
| dark red | 126 | 7 | 26 |
| flame yellowish orange | 242 | 153 | 0 |
| transparent bright orange | 235 | 117 | 13 |
| reddish brown | 90 | 27 | 11 |
| medium stone grey | 154 | 144 | 143 |
| dark stone grey | 75 | 92 | 85 |
| light stone grey | 227 | 227 | 217 |
| light royal blue | 133 | 190 | 232 |
| bright purple | 221 | 55 | 138 |
| light purple | 237 | 156 | 194 |
| cool yellow | 254 | 254 | 152 |
| medium lilac | 43 | 20 | 118 |
| light nougat | 243 | 191 | 135 |
| phosph. green | 252 | 250 | 211 |
| warm gold | 168 | 125 | 44 |
| dark brown | 46 | 13 | 4 |
| transparent bright green | 151 | 253 | 100 |
| medium nougat | 168 | 124 | 84 |
| white | 255 | 255 | 255 |
| black | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| transparent yellow | 248 | 238 | 104 |
| transparent flourescent reddish-orange | 229 | 100 | 70 |
| transparent red | 22 | 40 | 39 |
| transparent light blue | 181 | 223 | 233 |
| transparent blue | 78 | 175 | 230 |
| transparent green | 97 | 176 | 108 |
| transparent flourescent green | 242 | 238 | 92 |
| transparent | 240 | 240 | 240 |
| bright yellow | 255 | 197 | 2 |
| bright red | 220 | 0 | 12 |
| bright blue | 2 | 89 | 169 |
| dark green | 3 | 126 | 43 |
| nougat | 215 | 116 | 66 |
| bright green | 1 | 150 | 37 |
| brick-yellow | 218 | 188 | 125 |
| dark orange | 165 | 60 | 20 |

Comment: First things first, you'll need to clearly define what you mean by "closest" in some concrete way. There are a lot of factors to consider here. For example, do you prefer hue over saturation? brightness over hue? How do you resolve ties? Are you basing this on color perception or sheer numeric similarity? Is RGB even the best color space to use to achieve these goals? Beyond that it should be trivial to apply that function to a collection of pixel values.

Comment: Could you edit this to explain the _photographic_ issue you're trying to solve here? At the moment, this reads like an abstract image editing problem, which would be off-topic here. Thanks!

Comment: @Philip I want to convert a JPEG image to an image built from physical coloured squares.

Answer (score 6):

The general term is [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization).

When this is done on purpose for artistic effect, this is called [posterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization) (hence the name of the filters in Gimp and Photoshop).

Answer (score 1):

This is called indexed color. GIF uses indexed color up to 256 levels. You can set GIF's color levels to anything less than 256.

Comment: How would I apply indexed colour to a JPEG image?

Comment: @boardrider, in order to process the pixels, you'll need to render the jpeg image as actual pixel values, so the source format is not relevant to your algorithm, however, if you attempt to save the converted pixels as a jpeg, the compression algorithm will introduce artifacts, resulting in pixels not in your table

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are over 16 million colors possible in an 8-bit jpeg. And what you want to do can't be done easily as the encoded color space for a jpeg is Y'CbCr, not RGB... you would have to decode the jpeg file first using the appropriate color profile.

https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/

But if what you want to do is *convert an image* using your own limited color table, that's pretty easy in photoshop...